# Julia: How to change color of a group in plotly scatterplot

Tags: plotly, julia, uicolor, plotly.js

Say I have the following example code

```
using PlotlyJS
using CSV, DataFrames

df = dataset(DataFrame, "iris")
plot(
    df, x=:sepal_width, y=:sepal_length, color=:species,
    mode="markers"
)
```

[image]
**How could I go about specifying the color for each group** e.g. if I want setosa to be yellow instead?

It's exactly this [Plotly-Express: How to fix the color mapping when setting color by column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59713016/plotly-express-how-to-fix-the-color-mapping-when-setting-color-by-column-name) **but I need it in julia**. I could not get the color_discrete_map to work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite as convenient as just setting a `color_discrete_map`, but you can do it like this:

```
julia> species_color_map = Dict("setosa"     => "yellow",
                                "versicolor" => "aqua",
                                "virginica"  => "red")
Dict{String, String} with 3 entries:
  "virginica"  => "red"
  "setosa"     => "yellow"
  "versicolor" => "aqua"

julia> plot([scatter(
           subdf,
           x = :sepal_width,
           y = :sepal_length,
           name = subdf[1, :species],
           marker_color = species_color_map[ subdf[1, :species] ],
           mode = "markers"
       )
       for subdf in groupby(df, :species)])
```

This is pretty much what the `plot(df, ..., color=:species)` call does [underneath](https://github.com/sglyon/PlotlyBase.jl/blob/master/src/dataframes_api.jl#L395), in a more generic way. Unfortunately, I don't see a way to plug into that and just customize the colours based on value.